# Sum up number close to a specific number in a list

Tags: python, sum

I want to produce a list which includes so many numbers close to 80 and not larger than 100 and smaller than 60. And if the number not close to 80 just divide
Next number into many part and add the fronted  part to be more close to 80.the latter part just keep it and keep combing with next number to get close to 80.The range still between 60 and 100.if front one added the latter one can produce a number between 60 and 100 then just do it.
Like [35,62,35,200]
I want the result be [35+62,35+45,80,75]
200 divide into 45 80 75

Not [35+45,17+35+28,80,80,12]

Example 1

List = [12,40,30,53,82,31,100]

The result like [82,80,86,100]
Because of [12+40+30,53+27,55+31,100]

82 divide into 27 & 55

Example 2

List =[45,102,31,25,2,99]
Result = [45+35,67+31,25+2+53,46]=[80,98,80,46]

102 divide into 35 & 67
99 divide into 53 & 46

Please help me figure out how to code with this question, really appreciate it.

I have tried

For i in range(len(List)):

Comment: "*I have tried `For i in range(len(List)):`*": not sure if this is serious... Far from an honest attempt

Comment: I suggest that you start by stepping away from the computer and thinking about how you would solve this problem by hand. What steps would you take if I gave you a list of numbers on a piece of paper? Think about this very carefully and then write those steps on a piece of paper.